# FFMPEG: how to correctly convert avi containing "rawvideo, bgr24" to mp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, avi

I have `.avi` file:

```
$ ffprobe input.avi -hide_banner
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Duration: 00:01:08.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 182785 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 1060x615, 182915 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 20 tbn

$ file input.avi
input.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 1060 x 615, 20.00 fps, video: uncompressed
```

Here we see "rawvideo, bgr24".

I've already tried multiple ffmpeg invocations, but either the `.mp4` cannot be played in Windows 10 Photos app:

[image]

either the `.mp4` played incorrectly in some another player:
[image]

Note: however, VLC plays such `.mp4` well.

A simple question: how to *correctly* convert `.avi` containing "rawvideo, bgr24" to `.mp4` (so it can be played correctly in any player)?

Comment: Can you please post your FFmpeg command? Is it just: `ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp4`?

Comment: @Rotem I've tried multiple FFmpeg invocations... Probably it was `ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output.mp4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default output pixel format of FFmpeg (H.264 codec) is `yuv444p`.

For some reason Microsoft **Movies & TV** player doesn't support H.264 with `yuv444p` pixel format (at least not "out of the box").

For higher portability, select `yuv420p` pixel format:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

It's better to select the codec, and set `crf` (quality) parameter (not relying on the defaults):

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

---

In general I can't recommend using Movies & TV, but for some reason Microsoft decided it's the default player in Windows 10...

Comment: It says: `[libx264 @ 0000020367db82c0] height not divisible by 2 (1060x615)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Answer: add `-vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2"`. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20848224/1778275).